# Question regarding Performance when using ChangeNotifierProvider

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-state

i have implemented a Dark/Light-Mode in my app using Streams.
My problem is, that the change of the colors is very laggy.

Everywhere in my code are snippets like this:

```
Provider.of<ThemeMode>(context) == ThemeMode.light
                                    ? Colors.black : Colors.white
```

That's why i decided to write a small ChangeNotifierProvider: ColorState

```
class ColorState with ChangeNotifier {
  ThemeModel _themeModel = ThemeModel();

  Color _textColor = Colors.black;
  Color get textColor => _textColor;

  Color _backgroundColor = Colors.white;
  Color get backgroundColor => _backgroundColor;

  listenToModeChange() {
    _themeModel.themeStream.listen((newMode) {
      if (newMode == ThemeMode.light) {
        _textColor = Colors.black;
        _backgroundColor = Colors.white;
        notifyListeners();
      } else {
        _textColor = Colors.white;
        _backgroundColor = Color(0xff121212);
        notifyListeners();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Now i replaced a lot of these small Snippets with newer ones looking like this:

`backgroundcolor: Provider.of<ColorState>(context).backgroundColor,`

or

`color: Provider.of<ColorState>(context).textColor`

Now my whole UI is laggy. I though i was being clever by getting rid of these Ternary-situations. Seems like listening to a ChangeNotifierProvider so many times through my App is much slower? I dont know, i expected it to be smoother. Seems to be the opposite now.

Also:
I know there is a possibility to use and customize ThemeData for Dark/Light modes but i dont always need the same color in my app. Thats why i have to set the color manually in different locations.

My question is: Is there any better solution for this? Should i stay using ternary-operators?
Is listening to a provider for maybe 100 times really that slow?

Comment: What version of flutter are you using? `ChangeNotifier` should be able to handle 100 listeners in newer versions.

Comment: I am using Flutter version 2.2.0

Comment: hi .. i am using about 5 Change notifiers in my app.. Enclosed in Specific section of widgets .. Just the declaration is available at main function.. i want to ask how many change notifiers can i use... which should not slow down the application ?